# Как прижать панель к нижнему краю окна?

Tags: java, swing

Есть форма, вот код:

```
package lrr.forms.transfer.multiply;

import jk.swing.BoxLayoutUtils;
import libertyreserve.api.ApiAgent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * User: Jakeroid
 * Date: 2/28/12
 * Time: 7:53 PM
 */
public class MultiplyDialog extends JDialog {

    private List<TransferInfo> items;
    private MultiplyTable transferTable;
    private JButton jBtnAdd, jBtnEdit, jBtnDelete, jBtnClose;

    private void initComponents() {
        items = new ArrayList<TransferInfo>();
        transferTable = new MultiplyTable(items);
        items.add(new TransferInfo("pa11", "1221", ApiAgent.Currency.USD, "123"));
        jBtnAdd = new JButton("Добавить");
        jBtnEdit = new JButton("Редактировать");
        jBtnDelete = new JButton("Удалить");
        jBtnClose = new JButton("Закрыть");
    }

    private void initListeners() {
        jBtnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        jBtnEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        jBtnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        jBtnClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void buildForm() {
        JPanel mainPanel = BoxLayoutUtils.createVerticalPanel();
        //mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(12, 12, 12, 12));

        JPanel tablePanel = BoxLayoutUtils.createVerticalPanel();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        //scrollPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        scrollPane.add(transferTable);
        scrollPane.add(transferTable.getTableHeader());
        tablePanel.add(scrollPane);

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        JPanel buttonsPanelGrid = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanelGrid.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4, 5, 0));
        buttonsPanelGrid.add(jBtnAdd);
        buttonsPanelGrid.add(jBtnEdit);
        buttonsPanelGrid.add(jBtnDelete);
        buttonsPanelGrid.add(jBtnClose);
        buttonsPanel.add(buttonsPanelGrid);

        mainPanel.add(tablePanel);
        mainPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(12));
        mainPanel.add(buttonsPanel);

        getContentPane().add(mainPanel);

        pack();
    }

    public MultiplyDialog(JFrame owner, boolean modal) {
        super(owner, modal);
        initComponents();
        initListeners();
        buildForm();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

При изменении размеров окна, панель с кнопками растягивается, и занимает лишнее пространство, а нужно, что бы панель с кнопками была не изменялась. При этом растягивалась панель с таблицей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте GridBagLayout, там в конструкторе можно указать каким образом элемент должен растягиваться (горизонтально, вертикально, во всех направлениях или же вообще не должен) и к какому краю его прижать. почитайте вот [это](http://skipy.ru/technics/layouts.html).